# Pagereference not working in lightning populating values

Tags: apex, visualforce

It does not populate the **CF00X30000005Z00Y_lkid** in lightning. But it does it classic.

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/00y/e?CF00X30000005Z00Y=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(oRU.Name, 'UTF-8') + '&CF00X30000005Z00Y_lkid=' + oRU.Id + '&retURL=%2F' + oRU.Id + '&saveURL=%2F' + oRU.Id);
```

Comment: URL Hacks are deprecated in lightning, you have to use actions,https://www.salesforceben.com/migrate-your-salesforce-url-hacks-to-actions/

Comment: It is an apex commandbutton within a visualforce page, what is a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use URL hacking to pre-populate fields in Lightning.

Here is a possible solution:
https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdx-record-create-url-component